# In calculating depreciation

Tags: arithmetic

If the rate of depriciation is more than 100%, the outcome in one would come 0 and next should come the negative value of the initial.
However if we take a example,
Initial = 500
Time = 2 years
Rate = 100%
The outcome in second comes in postive value due to the even power . 
I used the formulae -
Outcome = Initial(1- (rate/100))²
Is there an external applicable formulae?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

if after 1 year you have nothing left, the depreciation in the second year is irrelevant, you still have nothing, and that is what the formula says, 1-100/100=0 and 0^2=0
 trula

Comment: I expexted.the negative result. I mean for a formulae which is universal.

Comment: why do you expect a negativ result? The universal formula gives you 0 and just simple reasoning also? trula

Comment: 100% was for an example.

Comment: If the rate is 200%, the result is not even negative.